# Python with tkinter aspect ratio issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to create a simple window that maintains a square shape when resized, using [python](/questions/tagged/python) 3.6.4 and [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) 8.6. Here is my code that produces a window, but does not maintain its aspect ratio when resized.

```
import tkinter as tk
w = tk.Tk()
w.aspect(1,1,1,1)
w.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't get `.aspect()` to do anything on either a Windows or Linux system here, so I guess it's just broken.

Comment: ah that sucks, guess I will have to try something else.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a canvas to make that, he detect event (image size changed) and .place relative x and relative y. I tryed make a script to help you, but you need make somes changes

```
from tkinter import *
# create a canvas with no internal border
canvas = Canvas(bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
lastw, lasth = canvas.winfo_width(), canvas.winfo_height()

# track changes to the canvas size and draw
# a rectangle which fills the visible part of
# the canvas

def configure(event):
    global lastw, lasth
    canvas.delete("all")
    w, h = event.width, event.height
    try:
        label.config(font = ('Arial ', int(12 * ((w - lastw) / (h - lasth))))) # -- this formula need change :3
    except ZeroDivisionError: pass
    lastw, lasth = canvas.winfo_width(), canvas.winfo_height()

canvas.bind("<Configure>", configure)
label = Label(canvas, text = "YOLO")
label.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5) # - this make the widget automatic change her pos

mainloop()
```

you can see how this work here http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-window-size.htm