# Python Canvas bind and resize

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When the window is resized, I want the height to be set equal to the width so the windows always is a square. In the code below `print(event.width)` does print the new window width, but  `canvas.configure(height=event.width)` doesn't change the canvas height. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I want the whole window to stay squared.

````
import tkinter as tk
from timeit import default_timer as timer

start_timer = timer()

height = 600
width = 600

red = ("#ff7663")

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=height, width=width, background=red)
canvas.pack(expand=True,fill="both")

def resize(event):
    end_timer = timer()
    if end_timer - start_timer > 0.5:
        print(event.width)
        canvas.configure(height=event.width)

canvas.bind("<Configure>", resize)

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: I think the binding needs to be on the `root` window: `root.bind("<Configure>", resize)`. But to be honest I'm not sure I understand what issue you're having. When I `canvas.pack(expand=True,fill="both")`, the canvas automatically takes up the whole root window regardless of its initial `width` or `height`, and fills the window on resize. Do you want the canvas to be square even when the root window isn't?

Comment: Are you wanting the whole window to stay square, or only the canvas?

Comment: My bad, I want the whole window to stay squared.

Comment: I've been looking into `root.wm_aspect` (i.e., `tk.aspect`), but apparently it [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861856/python-with-tkinter-aspect-ratio-issue) [work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495675/tkinter-aspect-ratio)...I'm at a loss, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the size of the canvas won't override the size created by the user. If you're wanting the whole window to remain square you must explicitly set the size of the window.

For example:

```
def resize(event):
    width = root.winfo_width()
    root.wm_geometry(f"{width}x{width}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but this example maintains a square `canvas` regardless of window size*:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk
root.geometry('600x600')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, background=red)
canvas.pack()


def on_resize(event):
    w, h = event.width, event.height
    if w <= h:
        canvas.configure(width=w, height=w)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.bind('<Configure>', on_resize)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Unless the window is resized to be narrower/shorter than the initial geometry given*